# Does $\cos (a) + i\sin (a) = 0$ have a solution in complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does
$$\cos (a) + i\sin (a) = 0$$ have  a solution in complex numbers?

Comment: No solutions exist.

Comment: $e^x \to 0 \space when \space x\to -\infty$

Answer (score 7):

For any $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
$$ \cos(z) + i\sin(z)
= e^{iz}
= e^{i(x+iy)}
= e^{-y + ix}
= e^{-y}e^{ix}.
$$
Note that $e^{ix}$ is of unit modulus, and that $e^{-y}$ is strictly greater than zero for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$.  From this, it follows that
$$ | \cos(z) + i\sin(z) |
=\left| e^{-y} e^{ix} \right|
= e^{-y}
\ne 0.
$$
Thus there are no solutions to the equation
$$ \cos(a) + i\sin(a) = 0,$$
even if we allows $a$ to be complex.

Comment: It makes me question: is there a generalization of numbers such that the solution exists? As @roshanaie said will that number be infintely large like a hyperreal?

Answer (score 0):

By Euler's formula, $\cos(x) + i\sin(x) = e^{ix}$. It is easy to see that the exponential function is never zero:

Assume that $e^z = 0$. Then $1 = e^0 = e^{z-z} = e^z e^{-z} = 0$, contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

The trigonometric form of complex number does not make sense if z=0 because the arguement is not defined in this case